# How to read data from a measurement device?

Tags: communication, serial-communication

I need to read data from a measurement device and then save them in a file.

In this photo there is a list of commands (with check_sum that I don't know where to get) I can use for the communication:
[Command List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d12ja.jpg)

Any help on how can I do that?

Comment: If "A" produces a checksum of 191 then it is probably 256 - ((sum of bytes) % 256).   Also matches "TEST" = 192.  Surely another page describes how it is computed.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you know a way to send this commands to the device? I have already tried with a serial terminal but I don't get any answer.